# Transfer file from client to server over socket in java

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to upload a file from a client to the server using sockets in JAVA. It is partially working, however, the file that gets created on the server is an empty text file. Can anyone offer any suggestions as to where I may have an issue. Thanks:

Server:

```
        private void handleFileUpload(String fileSizeInBytes, String fileName) throws IOException{
        String fullyQualifiedFileName = rootDirectory+System.getProperty("file.separator")+fileName;
        File fileToWrite = new File(fullyQualifiedFileName);
        if(fileToWrite.exists()){
            fileToWrite.delete();
        }

        int bytesRead = 0;
        byte[] aByte = new byte[1];
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
        BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;

        try {
            inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
            fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(fullyQualifiedFileName);
            bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
            bytesRead = inputStream.read(aByte, 0, aByte.length);
            baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            do {
                baos.write(aByte);
                bytesRead = inputStream.read(aByte);
            } while (bytesRead != -1);

            bufferedOutputStream.write(baos.toByteArray());
            bufferedOutputStream.flush();
            bufferedOutputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Client:

```
            private void uploadFile(Socket socket, File fileToUpload){
    byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) fileToUpload.length()];
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileToUpload);
        BufferedOutputStream toServer =  new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
        toServer.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
        toServer.flush();
        toServer.close();
        return;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        handleServerError("upload file", ex);
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

Comment: why read one byte at a time? why not like `1024` or maybe a little less..

Comment: I've tried many approaches, none seem to work

Comment: `baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();`  This is doing nothing... I believe this is your problem.

Comment: Maybe you want  `bufferedOutputStream.write(aByte);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `handleFileUpload` method as following

```
   private void handleFileUpload(String fileSizeInBytes, String fileName) throws IOException{
        String fullyQualifiedFileName = rootDirectory+System.getProperty("file.separator")+fileName;
        File fileToWrite = new File(fullyQualifiedFileName);
        if(fileToWrite.exists()){
            fileToWrite.delete();
        }

        int bytesRead = 0;
        byte[] aByte = new byte[1024];
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
        BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;

        try {
            inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
            fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(fullyQualifiedFileName);
            bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
            bytesRead = inputStream.read(aByte, 0, aByte.length);
            while (bytesRead != -1) {
                bufferedOutputStream.write(aByte, 0, bytesRead);
                bytesRead = inputStream.read(aByte, 0, aByte.length);
            } 

            bufferedOutputStream.flush();
            bufferedOutputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```